# Decomposers produce acid and depend on (liquid) water to perform their function. Is this world coherent?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, biology

About my idea:

**The decomposers of this world perform the degradation by producing and diluting acid in liquid water molecules.**

In this world, most decomposers are present in the seas and oceans.  However, they are also found in the humidity of the air or in heavy clouds. In order for them to perform their natural task - the decomposition of dead organisms - they need to come into contact with the water present in their bodies and then work. Decomposers can reach these bodies through the moisture present in the air - the air always has some moisture in this world because the surface is very fragmented into small portions of earth -, or through the rains - which are acidic due to their presence in association with liquid water. To avoid the presence of decomposers, either to preserve food or to clean it, extreme temperatures are used, in which the water enters solidification or evaporation.

*The plants (producers)* of this world play the main role of filtering water for animals (consumers), as they feed on the decomposers present in it - they have developed several ways of carrying out this activity, from foliage in the form of a filter for the capture and  filtration of rainwater along the branches to the plants partially submerged and with glassy foliage, capable of concentrating sunlight in the perimeter they cover, causing greater evaporation, from which the decomposers that come with the water capture. Because of this, most grow close to water, either on the coasts and coastlines, or on lakes and rivers. The smaller the portion of water and the greater the amount of flora around it, the lower the acidity in the water will be, given that the greater the amount of decomposers being consumed by plants.

As stated before, *animals* - terrestrial, mainly because marine ones are adapted to higher levels of acidity - depend on water "filtered" by plants. However, animals themselves in general need a certain amount of acid in the water they drink, as their bodies do not produce stomach acid on their own.  This acid assists in the breakdown of food in the stomach and is therefore absolutely necessary for the digestive process.  In a way, food is also more important than hydration, since drinking only water for long periods causes the accumulation of acid present in the stomach, which will not find food to corrode and will eventually affect the stomach wall - the consequences could vary from  something like an ulcer in our world until an internal hemorrhage caused by the perforation of the wall that lines the stomach.

Goals & observations:

- I would like to check if my idea makes sense.  If not, which parts are inconsistent, or could be improved and how;
- I am not looking for an idea perfectly congruent with science, but that just does not go incoherently against basic science;
- Forgive me for my English, I'm Brazilian and I'm still learning.

Answer (score 2):

> animals themselves in general need a certain amount of acid in the water they drink, as their bodies do not produce stomach acid on their own. This acid assists in the breakdown of food in the stomach and is therefore absolutely necessary for the digestive process.

I think here is a flaw. If animals and plants are able to live in an environment with acid water, I doubt acid could be of any help in digestion, as any organism would be made in such a way to not react to acids.

Answer (score 2):

There are many problems

There has to be decomposers. If there are consumers on land, there will be consumers that figure out they can eat dead things, which do not fight back as much. If they can digest living organisms they can digest dead ones.

Also stomach acid is produced to kill bacteria, if it does not do this is is useless. It can't do this if it is the same PH as rain water, even if your rain water is acidic, becasue the bacteria has to survive in this water.

The biggest problem it is impossible for a living thing to not be able to produce acid, a large portion of essential organic molecules and organic byproducts are acids. DNA and Proteins are made of acids. You cannot use organic chemistry an not have an overwhelming abundance of ways to make acids.